# Difference between returning address and returning a pointer in c++ function

Tags: c++, pointers, function-pointers

when passing a=4, the given functions returns :

```
int* temp1(int a)
{
   int b = a*2;
   return &b;
}

int* temp2(int a)
{
   int b = a*2;
   int *p = &b;
   return p;
}

int main()
{
   cout << *temp1(4);  // error
   cout << *temp2(4);  // output = 8
}
```

Why these above two functions have different behaviour?
Whereas, the below have same outputs?

```
int a = 3;
cout << *(&a); // 3
```

and

```
int a= 3;
int *p = &a;
cout << *p; // 3
```

Comment: Both functions are undefined behavior: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope)

Comment: There is no difference, but beware you are returning the address of a local variable (allocated on the function's stack frame) which is automatically deallocated when the function call is finished so the caller is pointing to invalid memory.

Answer (score 4):

The behavior of both of your functions is identical.  Both return a pointer to a local variable.  The pointed-to objects' lifetimes both end when the function returns.  Therefore the behavior of your program is undefined if it dereferences either of the returned pointers.

Comment: The last part is a very good point. It's only UB if you actually attempt to use the returned pointer. Although then you question what is the point of a function returning a pointer if using that pointer is not allowed.